# Rolling percentiles

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

Small rep of my data set:

```
TEAM1 <- c("ATL", "CHI", "CLE", "DET", "GSW", "NOP", "BKN","ATL", "PHI","CHI")
HOME.AWAY <- c("vs.", "vs.", "@", "@", "vs.", "@", "vs.","vs.", "@","@")
TEAM2 <- c("DET", "CLE", "CHI", "ATL", "NOP", "GSW", "CHI","PHI", "ATL","BKN")
DATE <- as.Date(c("2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-14",
       "2015-05-14","2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-15","2015-05-15",
       "2015-05-15","2015-05-15"))
PTS <- c(94, 97, 95, 106, 111, 95, 100,112,87, 94)
df <- data.frame(TEAM1,HOME.AWAY,TEAM2,PTS,DATE)

df

   TEAM1 HOME.AWAY TEAM2 PTS       DATE
   ATL       vs.   DET  94 2015-05-14
   CHI       vs.   CLE  97 2015-05-14
   CLE         @   CHI  95 2015-05-14
   DET         @   ATL 106 2015-05-14
   GSW       vs.   NOP 111 2015-05-14
   NOP         @   GSW  95 2015-05-14
   BKN       vs.   CHI 100 2015-05-15
   ATL       vs.   PHI 112 2015-05-15
   PHI         @   ATL  87 2015-05-15
   CHI       vs.   BKN  94 2015-05-15
```

The dataframe is organized by team level. So each game, will create two rows of data. For example, Atlanta vs Detroit (first row) and Detroit vs Atlanta (fourth row). The dataframe then includes the boxscore (PTS, REB, AST...) for the TEAM1. For this example I only included the Points scored variable.

I have been able to create a rolling mean and rolling median variable for each team:

```
df<- df[order(df$DATE),]

df <- df %>% group_by(TEAM1) %>% 
  mutate(PTS_YTD = lag(runMean(PTS, n=1, cumulative=TRUE),1))

df <- df %>% group_by(TEAM1) %>% 
  mutate(PTS_YTD = lag(runMedian(PTS, n=1, cumulative=TRUE),1))
```

I would like to create new variables with more information on the distribution of the PTS variable. For example, I would like to create 4 new variables:

- Percentile 25% for PTS
- Percentile 40% for PTS
- Percentile 60% for PTS
- Percentile 75% for PTS

These new variables should be rolling just like runMean for the mean.

Comment: So `runMean` and `runMedian` seem to be from the `TTR` package, correct? Could you add this to your code?

Comment: Check the `runquantile` in package `caTools`: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/caTools/html/runquantile.html

Comment: Thanks. how would you use the runquantile function? it doesn't work for me.